# Windows Phone Resize an Image with a Storyboard

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, resize, transition

I simply have an Image, and I set its width and height by assigning some numbers. For example, First Height and Width: 400 x 800. Second Height and Width: 200 x 400.

So if you do such a mainstreamed thing, there won't be any transition when resizing it, it just gets smaller immediately in a blink of eye. But I want it to resize between those "specific" measurements by transition (or animating) in 1 or 2 seconds.

I know Microsoft Expression Blend do some storyboards, but I could not do this by data binding. I databinded this image with a value, when the value changes, image resizes also. But I could not record any storyboard to create a transition.

What do you suggest me to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something along the lines of this might work...

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CreateAnimation(400, 200).Begin();
}

private Storyboard CreateAnimation(double from, double to)
{
    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    DoubleAnimation Animation = new DoubleAnimation();
    Animation.From = from;
    Animation.To = to;
    Animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));

    Storyboard.SetTarget(Animation, ITEMNAME);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(Animation, new PropertyPath("(Width)"));

    sb.Children.Add(Animation);

    return sb;
}
```

Just create two double animations for the height and width to use simultaneously.